# Faulty positions of error bars in bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, errorbar

It seems like some of my error bars were right below the bars themselves, instead of ± from the mean. Would appreciate it if there's any advice on this.

My plot
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NBfG.png)

My script

```
psbs <- read_csv("psbs.csv")
spsbs<-summarySE(data=psbs, measurevar="fv", groupvars=c("Line", "genotype"))

P1<- ggplot(data=psbs, mapping = aes(x = factor(genotype), y = fv, fill= Line))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")+
  geom_errorbar(data=spsbs, aes(ymin=fv-se, ymax=fv+se), width=.35, position=position_dodge(width= 0.9))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 13))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())+
  facet_wrap(~genotype,scales="free")+
  ylim(0,1.0)+
  labs(x = element_blank(), y="Fv/Fm", fill= "Line")
```

My data frame

```
data.frame(psbs)
   id genotype Line   fv
1   1     PsbS L1.1 0.82
2   2     PsbS L1.1 0.82
3   3     PsbS L1.1 0.82
4   4     PsbS L1.2 0.82
5   5     PsbS L1.2 0.82
6   6     PsbS L1.2 0.82
7   7     PsbS L1.3 0.82
8   8     PsbS L1.3 0.82
9   9     PsbS L1.3 0.83
10 10     PsbS L1.4 0.82
11 11     PsbS L1.4 0.82
12 12     PsbS L1.4 0.82
13 13     PsbS L1.5 0.82
14 14     PsbS L1.5 0.83
15 15     PsbS L1.5 0.82
16 16     PsbS L1.6 0.82
17 17     PsbS L1.6 0.82
18 18     PsbS L1.6 0.83
19 19     PsbS L1.7 0.82
20 20     PsbS L1.7 0.82
21 21     PsbS L1.7 0.82
22 22     PsbS L1.8 0.83
23 23     PsbS L1.8 0.82
24 24     PsbS L1.8 0.82
25 25     PsbS L1.9 0.82
26 26     PsbS L1.9 0.83
27 27     PsbS L1.9 0.82
```

Comment: What does `summarySE` do? Where's it from?

Comment: @AndreWildberg 'summarySE' basically summarize my data into mean,SE,SD and ci, it main purpose here is to obtain the SE so that I can plot my error bars. It usually worked for me but somehow the error bars for this image looked wonky. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have multiple values or obs. per `Line` in your `psbs` dataframe. When using `geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")` you are plotting each of these values on top each other and hence the "bar"s reflect the maximum value per `Line`. If you want to show the mean then IMHO. you could simply use the `spsbs` dataframe for the bars too which already contains the mean value per `Line`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(Rmisc)

spsbs <- summarySE(data = psbs, measurevar = "fv", groupvars = c("Line", "genotype"))

ggplot(data = spsbs, mapping = aes(x = factor(genotype), y = fv, fill = Line)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = fv - se, ymax = fv + se), width = .35, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 13)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  facet_wrap(~genotype, scales = "free") +
  ylim(0, 1.0) +
  labs(x = element_blank(), y = "Fv/Fm", fill = "Line")
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
structure(list(id = 1:27, genotype = c("PsbS", "PsbS", "PsbS", 
"PsbS", "PsbS", "PsbS", "PsbS", "PsbS", "PsbS", "PsbS", "PsbS", 
"PsbS", "PsbS", "PsbS", "PsbS", "PsbS", "PsbS", "PsbS", "PsbS", 
"PsbS", "PsbS", "PsbS", "PsbS", "PsbS", "PsbS", "PsbS", "PsbS"
), Line = c("L1.1", "L1.1", "L1.1", "L1.2", "L1.2", "L1.2", "L1.3", 
"L1.3", "L1.3", "L1.4", "L1.4", "L1.4", "L1.5", "L1.5", "L1.5", 
"L1.6", "L1.6", "L1.6", "L1.7", "L1.7", "L1.7", "L1.8", "L1.8", 
"L1.8", "L1.9", "L1.9", "L1.9"), fv = c(0.82, 0.82, 0.82, 0.82, 
0.82, 0.82, 0.82, 0.82, 0.83, 0.82, 0.82, 0.82, 0.82, 0.83, 0.82, 
0.82, 0.82, 0.83, 0.82, 0.82, 0.82, 0.83, 0.82, 0.82, 0.82, 0.83, 
0.82)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
"27"))
```